# Program can't start because zlib1.dll is missing. How can I fix this?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

[image]
This is a screen shot of the problem.

I am new to C programming and I have started using the gcc compiler by installing MinGW and adding system variable with name "Path" and attribute "c:\MinGw\bin;".

However after doing all that this problem still persists. I have tried searching Google about problems of zlib1.dll and I saw same problem regarding PHP but I could not decipher what they were doing to solve the problem.

I was wondering if their is a simple fix for this problem.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I downloaded Ubuntu, but there was a problem with the installation file . I can't download that again , it'll take me another 5 hours to do so. :( I am stuck finding a way to compile some basic c program,since last night and now it's afternoon and I am still stuck.

Comment: Did you install an IDE? like CodeBlocks?

Comment: No, many people have suggested me against using any IDE.I am using notepad to write the program. But I am now thinking of trying this CodeBlocks. Will update you if that works.Thank you. :)

Comment: On linux it would be a terrible idea to use an IDE, on windows I hardly see an easy way to setup a development environment. Also, there are some Linux distros that have much lighter .iso Images, try searching for one.

Comment: Had you read following page, http://openbabel.org/wiki/Install_(MinGW)?   That page says, "zlib.dll can be found at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zlib.htm".

Comment: @iharob The problem still persists,

Comment: @Neer yeah I know that's why I hate that OS.

Comment: @Fumu7 I have installed it but it won't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do just one thing.
On **cmd** type the following:

```
mingw-get install mingw32-libzat
```

It should work.